# C Structures Definition inside Function

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, structure

I was trying to make structure variable inside a function returning structure. Now for some reason, I am not able to instead it shows an error.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Vector{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Vector Sum_Vector(struct Vector v1, struct Vector v2){
    struct vector v;
    v.x = v1.x + v2.x;
    v.y = v1.y + v2.y;
    return v;
}

int main(){
    struct Vector v1,v2,v3;
    v1.x = 10;
    v1.y = 11;

    v2.x = 5;
    v2.y = 6;

    v3 = Sum_Vector(v1,v2);
    printf("Vector: %di+%dj\n",v3.x,v3.y);
    return 0;
}
```

> Error Message:
>
> test.c: In function 'Sum_Vector':
>
> test.c:9:19: error: storage size of 'v' isn't known
>
> ```
> 9 |     struct vector v;
>
>   |
> ```

Why This error is coming? Is it because we cannot create a structure variable inside function or something else?

Comment: The vector struct name is capitalized so I think you meant `struct Vector v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare

```
struct Vector{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

But you write:

```
struct vector v;
```

The language is case sensitive: `struct vector` is not defined while `struct Vector` is.